# Print multiple variables from a sequence in Python 3

Tags: python

from a total newbie on Python, I´m trying to print the complete word with the end1,2,3 variables, and would like to have the output for the last line but without having to writing down each end´n´ variable, if that´s possible.

```
end1 = "C"
end2 = "h"
end3 = "e"

# not working as intended

for i in range(1, 4):
    print(f"end{i}")

# works but not ideal

print(end1+end2+end3)
```

Comment: This is the reason for the common admonishment not to put data in variable names. This should be `end = ['C', 'h', 'e']` and it would be simple.

Comment: Was running the 'hard way to learn py' exercises and wanted to give it a try, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This is one of the reasons that LPTHW is widely panned among Python programmers. It's really not that great, and teaches some pretty poor programming practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of python unpacking, in the following example `end_x` hold the reference to the tuple, while each of the `end_1..end_2` holds the reference to each of the corresponding strings:

```
end_x = end1, end2, end3 = ("C", "h", "e")

for end in end_x:
    print(end)
```

Or in case you wan to print just a line:

```
print("".join(end_x))
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/repls/HuskyDisguisedDictionaries)